# Unable to run jobs on SQL Server on my PC

Tags: sql-server

I have been trying to run an SSIS package in my C: from SSMS on my PC. I have scheduled a job as per below

[image]

And below is the error that I am getting

> Executed as user: .
>
> Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 14.0.1000.169 for 64-bit
>   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft. All rights reserved.
>
> Started:  11:15:37 AM
>   Error: 2019-10-03 11:16:28.52
>   Code: 0x000002C0
>   Source: Address Connection manager "ORACLE_v"
>   Description: OCI error encountered. ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
>   End Error
>
> Error: 2019-10-03 11:16:28.52
>   Code: 0x0000020F
>   Source: Data Flow Task Oracle Source [70]
>   Description: The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager ORACLE_v500 failed with error code 0x80004005. There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.    > End Error
>
> Error: 2019-10-03 11:16:28.52
>   Code: 0xC0047017
>   Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline
>   Description: Oracle Source failed validation and returned error code 0x80004005.    > End Error
>
> Error: 2019-10-03 11:16:28.52
>   Code: 0xC004700C
>   Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline
>   Description: One or more component failed validation. End Error
>
> Error: 2019-10-03 11:16:28.52
>   Code: 0xC0024107
>   Source: Data Flow Task
>   Description: There were errors during task validation.  End Error
>
> DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
>
> Started:  11:15:37 AM Finished: 11:16:28 AM  Elapsed: 50.625 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

I am not sure why I am getting these errors. I can run that package from SSIS and it is not giving me any connection issues.

Comment: . 'ORA-12154: TNS:'. look like a connection issue to oracle source. Check through each error message.

Answer (score 1):

create a proxy account you know can access the Oracle source.

then run the agent under the proxy account you've set up.

[image]